# image resizing and controls layout shifting

Tags: wpf

Can you give an idea on xaml layout such that image is on the right and some content on the right.
And when image becomes larger, so the content shifts to the right?
I could probably put a two columns grid and programmatically enlarge image and making column 0 bigger, but there is must be a proper way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a control that doesn't automatically adjust the size of its children based on available space, such as a Horizontal StackPanel

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image ... />
    <ContentControl .... />
</StackPanel>
```

If I misunderstood you and you actually want the content to resize based on available space, then use a control that automatically adjusts the size of its children based on available space, such as a `DockPanel`

```
<DockPanel>
    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" ... />
    <ContentControl .... />
</DockPanel>
```

When I first started working with WPF, I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) very useful for figuring out what sort of panels I wanted to use to layout my controls

Comment: Thanks, Rachel.  You seem to be the only adequate person to answer my wpf questions.  Others just prefer to give me minuses).  StackPanel horizontal works as needed.

Comment: @Nickolodeon To be fair, you prefer to ask questions here instead of doing a little research on the problem first. That kind of behavior is generally discouraged on here, and asking stackoverflow to provide you with code instead of looking up the problem yourself will more than likely get you downvoted and people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Thanks for an advice.  The only research I know of when learning new technology is reading books from first pages.  However I am desperetly out of time for this task and have to humiliate myself by asking some elementary questions.  I still need to read on databinding and styling.  But learning wpf in 5 days to do what I need isn't feasible for me personally.

Comment: @Nickolodeon Some of the questions I've seen you ask could be quickly solved by using Google, or reading [the basics of WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx). It would be much faster to gain a quick understanding of the language, than to start coding immediately and stumble through it while waiting on SO answers. I feel the most important skill as a programmer is the ability to learn, and I really would not suggest a programming career to anyone who is not willing to learn new things constantly throughout his/her career.

Comment: I agree only in part.  In order to ask google one must already possess some jargon/keywords.  Sometimes asking questions in plain language on forums such as this will let other people to hint you with these keywords.  As to reading - I am kind of fed up with for right now and tried an easier way by askin dumb questions here.  And it worked, but partially.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean image on the left and additional content on the right?  Use width = auto for column 0 and width = * for column 1.